# Matrix from std vector to vector from Eigen/Dense

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, 3d, eigen

I try to read out elements from a 3D matrix created using the std c++ dynamic container for vectors. 
Below is how I initialize my matrix:

> `typedef vector<vector<vector<ClassA> > > matrix3D;`

In my class named "ClassA", I have the following public members:

> `double a, b, c;`

Then in my main file, I fill in the matrix with:

`double varA=M_PI; double varB=varA; double varC=varA;`

`matrix3D[i][j][k].a = varA;`

`matrix3D[i][j][k].b = varB;`

`matrix3D[i][j][k].c = varC;`

Now when I read the doubles into a vector created using Eigen/Dense library, the type of the vector becomes a matrix:

```
    Vector3d vectorEigen;
    vectorEigen << matrix3D[i][j][k].a, matrix3D[i][j][k].b, matrix3D[i][j][k].c;
```

and `vectorEigen` becomes a variable of the type `Eigen::Matrix<double, 3,1,0,3,1>`

Does anybody have a clue what I have missed here?

Comment: C++ is a statically typed language. A variable won't "become" a different type.

Comment: I presume the question about the type of `vectorEigen` is not the real issue anymore. Maybe you're wrestling with some other issue? Actually, don't you need `vectorEigen << matrix3D[i][j][k].a << matrix3D[i][j][k].b << matrix3D[i][j][k].c;` instead of `vectorEigen << matrix3D[i][j][k].a, matrix3D[i][j][k].b, matrix3D[i][j][k].c;`

Comment: `vectorEigen << matrix3D[i][j][k].a << matrix3D[i][j][k].b << matrix3D[i][j][k].c;` is giving me an error, unfortunately :( 
The problem occurs when I call the function which takes a Vector3d as input parameter. Substituting `vectorEigen` as input parameter of the function causes the compiler to complain. And the reason is the function with an input of the type `Eigen::Matrix<double, 3,1,0,3,1>` is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally Eigen represents vectors as matrices with only one column. So vectors (just like "ordinary" matrices) are really instances of an `Eigen::Matrix` template class.

For simplicity towards the programmer however, Eigen uses C++'s `typedef` to define vector classes that are synonyms for an `Eigen::Matrix<>` with specific options. For example, the `Vector3d` type in `Eigen` is a [typedef](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__matrixtypedefs.html#ga2006332f6989f501762673e21f5128f5) for a matrix whose elements are `double`s and that has 3 rows and 1 column:

```
typedef Matrix<double, 3, 1> Vector3d
```

The [Matrix](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Matrix.html) template class actually has 6 template arguments, the last 3 ones being default arguments. Here is the full signature:

```
template<typename _Scalar, int _Rows, int _Cols, int _Options, int _MaxRows, int _MaxCols>
class Eigen::Matrix< _Scalar, _Rows, _Cols, _Options, _MaxRows, _MaxCols >
```

If the compiler refers to `Eigen::Matrix<double, 3,1,0,3,1>` in error messages it's talking about an `Eigen::Matrix` with the following template parameters:

- `_Scalar`= double
- `_Rows` = 3
- `_Cols` = 1
- `_Options` = 0 (by default)
- `_MaxRows` = `_Rows` (by default) = 3
- `_MaxCols` = `_Cols` (by default) = 1

So `Eigen::Matrix<double, 3,1,0,3,1>` is just the full type of `Vector3d` that the compiler sees after resolving `typedef` and template arguments.

The type hasn't changed at all, you just use the `Vector3d` shorthand notation in your code, whereas the compiler refers to it by its explicit type.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
The problem is, I need that 'vectorEigen' as an input of a function which takes in a Vector3d input parameter. The compiler complains exactly at that line the function is called: functionA(vectorEigen), with the reason 'undefined reference' because the input type does not match.

Comment: @bull Did you include the correct Eigen header files? For example `#include <Eigen/Eigen>` (this basically includes all of Eigen, which is overdoing it, but may help you find the problem.)

Comment: I include `<Eigen/Dense>` but just changed to `<Eigen/Eigen>`. The error remains however...

Comment: Try to create a *small* program that reproduces your problem first. If then you still don't understand what's wrong then, feel free to come back for some help.

Comment: I just realized that the error lies in the function definition. Now everything works. Thank you for your explanation. At least I understand now that a Vector3d is in real a matrix and that is not supposed to cause any error. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

If you are just interested in implementing Matrix and Vector using C++, then you can totally ignore my answer.

But, if you just need to **use** Matrix and Vector, then you can try the [Mat](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a23b182c4ffd46abe38f460c1480ae887) and [Vec](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/d6/dcf/classcv_1_1Vec.html) class in [OpenCV](http://opencv.org). And [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html?highlight=mat) is a good tutorial about Mat.

In addition, if you don't necessarily need to use C++, then [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) is even more convenient.